# How to View & Edit SQL Database in a Web Site

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2015

Okay, so I am all new to this. I recently started a job that requires me working of a SQL Query displayed in HeidiSQL. So I decided to start learning SQL which led me to Visual Studio 2015 which has led me to frustration!

I keep reading I have to create a new Website. Okay done. Now go to GridView. What? Where? Where is this gridview option?

Please can someone point me in the right direction, with a tutorial, videos, anything!

Thank you.

Comment: You can use MS SQL SERVER :). No need of Website.

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong path completely? I want to learn how to build a Web App where I can view SQL data on a website. For example I have a table "Customers" and would like to view one customer and all their details in a pretty looking box on a website with the ability to edit them via the website. I have heard of Ruby on Rails do you think this would be a better route to go down? Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's depend on your technology fluency. Better to go with technology which is easy for you.